# Using Ghostscript Add watermark to PDF for Print Only

Tags: ghostscript

I am creating a program using ghostscript which add watermark(stamp) on pdf file. But I want to know, is it possible to add watermark to pdf which display only on print copy of that pdf not on computer screen?

Comment: theoretically, yes. postscript (which is basically what a pdf) is a programming language and can probably detect what the output environment is. but that's probably something you'd have to add into the raw potscript/pdf itself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this by creating an Optional Content Group which has a usage dictionary where the /Print dictionary has a PrintState key with the value ON. You will also want a /View dictionary with a ViewState key which has the value OFF.

You then create an annotation for the watermark and have that annotation be a part of the Optional Content Group created above. That annotation will then print, but will not view.

Note however that it is up to the consuming application to decide whether it is a Viewer or a Printer. Ghostscript, for example, always assumes that it is a Viewer and so uses the ViewState to determine the visibility of optional content groups.

You should be able to construct Optional Content Groups and Annotations by using pdfmark operations. See the Adobe pdfmark reference for more information.